# Understanding how to use k-means in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm noob to **k-means**, but I need to predict some data using k-means in javaScript.

I found some example codes [here](http://burakkanber.com/blog/machine-learning-k-means-clustering-in-javascript-part-1/) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/hdict/source/browse/gae/files/kmeans.js) and [here](http://www.mymessedupmind.co.uk/index.php/javascript-k-mean-algorithm).

As you can see, I have no problem with code, but with how to use it.

**My problem:**

I have this database, and I want to predict the boolean value. It works like this: I have many users, for each one I have some data stored from a game (tableA). Each game can be played by more than one user.

When I get some data from new game (all corresponding to tableA, and I have the option of knowing some data from relation table), I want to predict value of boolean value (win) for that user.
[image]

Please, I want to understand how the k-means works (an example will be great) so I can know what data do I need to send to k-means algorithm so I get the % of getting 1 in win

Thanks

Comment: k-means is **not a prediction algorithm**.

Comment: That may be the case. I saw people **use k-means to predict data**. Assuming you are right... What can I do to make a prediction on that value?

Comment: I am not sure, what is the input and what shoud be the output. Given the data from previous games, you want to take two users, that did not yet play and predict, who will win with what probability? k-means can take the data and partition it into clusters. For example players with similar stats, but will not help you in predictions.

Comment: maybe you were mixing up KMeans with kNN (k Nearest Neighbor?)